ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after npm start in VSCode
I´m working on a repository I downloaded to my workstation from my github account.
When trying to start a local host with the command npm start in Visual Code Edge returns a error

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

also the Terminal returns the following:
(...)

opensslErrorStack: [
'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error',
'error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported'
],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

I know the code is fine because it run well when I did a test in a IBM´s Lab environment IDE but i can´t preview on my local machine.
